# Definition of limit superior and limit inferior of real functions

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

In [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_inferior_and_limit_superior), the definition of limit superior and limit inferior of functions from metric spaces is:

> Take a metric space $X$, a subspace $E$ contained in $X$, and a function $f:E\to \mathbb {R}$. Define, for any limit point $a$ of $E$,
> $$\limsup _{x\to a}f(x)=\lim _{\varepsilon \to 0}\left(\sup \,\{f(x):x\in E\cap B(a,\varepsilon )\setminus \{a\}\}\right)$$
> and
> $$\liminf _{x\to a}f(x)=\lim _{\varepsilon \to 0}\left(\inf \,\{f(x):x\in E\cap B(a,\varepsilon )\setminus \{a\}\}\right)$$
> where $$B(a,\varepsilon )$$ denotes the metric ball of radius $\varepsilon$ about $a$.

From the definition above, why do we need the point $a$ is a limit point of $E$?

Thanks for any explanation.

Comment: Otherwise the set $E \cap B(a, \varepsilon) \setminus \{a\}$ would be empty for small enough $\varepsilon$ and the $\sup, \inf$ of empty set does exist in $\mathbb R$.